# obtaining the unit of observation for critical review of a research design

Tags: research-design

Hi I am writing a critical review for one of my assignments, and I am struggling to extract the unit of observation.

I have written a critical review for one of my assessments at university which is a data analysis course and looks at research design in social sciences. I have since second guessed myself as to whether my judgement was correct and was seeking a further opinion.
The article looks at whether or not native Swiss commuters are likely to help high to low status immigrants and operationalises this by measuring whether native commuters assist confederate immigrants. The researchers then run a regression analysis on the data collected

The unit of an analysis is at a group level for (immigrant groups) as that is what they are making inferences about. I had originally thought that the unit of observation was at an individual level as they collected data on the native commuters such as age , ethnicity and gender (this however was a guess as it was done covertly) I however wondered if it was actually at the group level as they are making inferences about immigrant groups

The link to the article is below in case that is preferred over my explanation :https://academic.oup.com/esr/article/35/4/582/5512302#140154323

Comment: Greetings Lisa! I would recommend providing a more context to your question, specifically why you raise the questions you do about observations being group/individual level. It will show us what you have done so far as well as how we can assist. Otherwise, this forces the answerer to do a lot more work to provide a solution.

Comment: Hi Shawn , Sorry for not explaining the question very well. I have written a critical review for one of my assessments at university which is a data analysis course and looks at research design in social sciences. I have since second guessed myself as to whether my judgement was correct and was seeking a further opinion. The article looks at whether or not native swiss commuters are likely to help high to low status immigrants and operationalises this by measuring native commuters assisting confederate immigrants.  The researchers then run a regression analysis on the data collected

Comment: The uni of an analysis is at a group level for (immigrant groups) as that is what they are making inferences about. I had originally thought that the unit of observation was at an individual level as they collected data on the native commuters such as age , ethnicity and gender (this however was a guess as it was done covertly) . But then I wondered if it was actually at the group level as they are making inferences about immigrant groups. Many thanks for replying to me I really appreciate it

Comment: Can you edit these comments into your question? It will be easier for people to read from there.